# Which is first? Activate Journey or Activate Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

What's the proper order of operations on Activating a journey that injects contacts right away?

I have an automation audience that I can set to a daily interval.

Do I activate the journey and delay the automation to say 3 minutes after activation.  Then the audience will properly inject?

Comment: First have your journey activated in  test mode and run automation using Run Once option. If you are satisfied with the results, go ahead and activate the journey. You can trigger automation using Run Once for immediate contact In jection and then schedule automation for next day as per your preference .

Comment: I've had issues with Test Mode injecting that test group and locking them out because of a 'no re-entry' parameter.  Test Mode is more like an 'inject but don't send' mode.

Comment: Yes Test Mode is used just to check if your journey configuration is fine or not. You can choose not to do that. In that case activate the journey and then activate automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Audience > Automation studio and have added your SQL/Filter to your automation, then activate you Journey first.

Journey Builder then automatically adds an audience refresh to your automation. Then run your automation when you are ready it wanting to inject the audience into the journey.

I personally like to clear out any records in the journey entry data extension before activate.